# How to prevent suggestions from showing in search fields on firefox or chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I'm trying to record a screencast that involves searching something on a website. Unfortunately, when I start typing the term, suggestions appear. How do I prevent these from showing?

I tried deleting the .mozilla directory, without success.

I'm on linux, ubuntu 18.04.

I need a solution either for chrome or firefox, not both.

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox there's an option "display search suggestions" in search preferences; just navigate to

```
about:preferences#search
```